# how does vim check file type?

Tags: vim

My vimrc is as below:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :wa<CR> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>

nnoremap <buffer> <F10> :wa<CR> :!make && ./%< && make clean<CR>

nnoremap <buffer> <F11> :wa<CR> :!gcc % -o %< && ./%< && rm %<<CR>
```

So I can use `<F9>`to build python and `<F11>` to build C.

I wonder if I can add some statements into vimrc so Vim can check the file type automatically and I can use only one hotkey to build different file by if...else statements.

Comment: Couldn't you make a shell script and have vim call that?  Then do the heavy lifting of file type detection in the shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aha I found a way to solve this problem by using `autocmd`

```
autocmd BufRead *.py nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :wa<CR> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
autocmd BufRead *.cpp nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :wa<CR> :!g++ % -o %< && ./%< && rm %<<CR>
autocmd BufRead *.c nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :wa<CR> :!gcc % -o %< && ./%< && rm %<<CR>
```

That is what I need !

Answer (score 1):

Create a file python.vim (the name does not matter) under the directory `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python` or equivalent on a different operating system.

Place the Python binding in it:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <F9> :wa<CR> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>
```

Do the same for C.